# Xamarin и ошибки компиляции

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, xamarin

Я пользуюсь Xamarin for VS2015. Летом я установил Xamarin на личный компьютер. Там до сих пор всё работает, там можно создавать приложения. Другое дело - рабочий компьютер. Туда я установил Xamarin в октябре. И пошло-поехало... Начнём с того, что как только я компилирую программу на каком либо устройстве, VS ждет, что-то делает, и говорит, мол, что при сборке возникли ошибки. А окно ошибок ничего не показывает.

Я думал, что проблема в эмуляторе( я бедное существо у которого нет смартфона). Поэтому использовал прилагающийся эмулятор от Google. Не работало. Просто не запускалось, хотя писало "Готово". После использования Nox Emulator, понял что просто код не так компилируется. APK файл появился - но не работает.

И да... Всё это шаблон, начальный код. То есть после создания проекта я ничего не менял. Не работает!

Что надо сделать, чтобы исправить проблему?

Comment: ну например приложить трейс ошибки для начала

Comment: Что такое трейс? Кстати забыл упомянуть, что окно ошибок ничего не видит.

Comment: stack trace  ошибки

Comment: Причём он тут? Это же класс. У меня код элементарно не выполняется. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: а в логе билда (Output/Build) ошибок нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бывают разные случаи. Когда такое возникает.

1. Чаще всего. Достаточно удалить bin и obj в проекте. И проблема уходит.
2. Проверяйте настройки проекта. Такие у меня настройки. Может стоять лишняя галочка предназначенная только для Release.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверьте Advanced properties / Support architectures  (для эмуляторов должны стоять галочки x86_64  и/или x86

4. В путях к sdk и ndk не должно быть русских символов
5. Обновите sdk, ndk до последних версий.
6. Если выше перечисленное не помогло. И Вы используете шаблонное приложение.
   Попробуйте переустановить sdk, ndk или обновить плагин для Visual Studio. Иногда помогает и это. Но это редкий случай.

   7. Не использовать эмуляторы Apache Cordova. Только от google либо Microsoft.

Примерные действия. Которые мне помогают решать такую проблему. Которая периодически возвращается.

Comment: Не подошло решение. Спасибо, конечно. Судя по всему проблема в ОС.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, ответ на вопрос нашёл самостоятельно, когда читал документацию к эмулятору... Заметим, что в каждом неудачном случае, я использовал слабые компьютеры. Поэтому, собственно говоря и возникла ошибка с эмулятором. Решение проблемы: купить смартфон и не мучаться.

Answer (score 0):

Не каждый смартфон будет работать,у меня на одном компе нормально эмуляцию делает,на другом просто беда,можно пробовать использовать разные эмуляторы,например есть эмулятор bluestack, у эмулятора от студии то-ли на 10,то-ли на 8ке бывают баги связанные с inteL HAXM  к примеру.